# Create New user using admin user in RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I want to create new user using admin user, however, get error doesn't have permission which probably no sysadmin roles due limitation from aws
[image]

so is there another way to create new user using my admin user?

Comment: aws not providing admin rights for RDS SQL Server 
for more details ask to aws support

Answer (score 1):

Your account should be in securityadmin group. When you want to create new user.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in AWS RDS - SQLSERVER

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQToq.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).